Tomcat problem on IDEA that ClassCastException
this is the Console's detail

24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Server built:          Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Server number:         7.0.75.0
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
OS Name:               Windows 11
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
OS Version:            10.0
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Architecture:          amd64
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
JVM Version:           1.8.0_371-b11
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\lhy.SmartTomcat\mmall\mmall
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\lhy.SmartTomcat\mmall\mmall
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\lhy.SmartTomcat\mmall\mmall\temp
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\lhy.SmartTomcat\mmall\mmall\conf\logging.properties
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=58237:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.5\bin
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Bandizip;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin;D:\Gradle8.4\gradle-8.4\bin;%MAVEN-HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\lhy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\lhy.dotnet\tools;;.
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8088"]
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Initialization processed in 557 ms
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Starting service Catalina
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\lhy.SmartTomcat\mmall\mmall\conf\Catalina\localhost\mmall.xml
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processServletContainerInitializers
Failed to detect ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/mmall]
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1579)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:198)
19 more
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24, 2024 2:01:57 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
24, 2024 2:01:58 下午 org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [929] milliseconds.
24, 2024 2:01:58 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Context [/mmall] startup failed due to previous errors
24, 2024 2:01:58 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\lhy.SmartTomcat\mmall\mmall\conf\Catalina\localhost\mmall.xml has finished in 1,239 ms
24, 2024 2:01:58 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8088"]
24, 2024 2:01:58 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
24, 2024 2:01:58 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
http://localhost:8088/mmall
Server startup in 1344 ms

and this is Access log:
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [24/May/2024:14:02:04 +0800] "GET /mmall HTTP/1.1" 404 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [24/May/2024:14:14:59 +0800] "GET /mmall HTTP/1.1" 404 -
i tried to open this web but failed.
at the begining of my project,i can run tomcat successfully,but now i run it again,it failed,how can i solve this problem?

Please try to use newer Tomcat version
